# distribution of coprime integers

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Let $0 < a < 1$ be fixed, and integer $n$ tends to infinity. It is not hard to show that the number of integers $k$ coprime to $n$ such that $1\leq k\leq an$ asymtotically equals $(a+o(1))\varphi(n)$.
The question is: what are the best known estimates for the remainder and where are they written?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Vinogradov, I. M. An introduction to the theory of numbers, Ch. 2, problem N 19. It gives error term $O(\tau(n))$. But direct application of inclusion-exclusion principle gives $O(2^{\omega(n)})$ (where $\tau$ is the number of divisors, and $\omega$ is the number of prime divisors. Standart solution with Mobius function also gives $O(2^{\omega(n)})$ if one take into account that $\mu(p^2)=0.$

Comment: Alexey, is that really the way you spell your surname?

Comment: It's my fault: I asked Alexey (Ustinov) to answer so he didn't pay enough attention to filling in his data accurately.

Comment: Now my name is correct.

Answer (score 4):

In a similar question [Bound the error in estimating a relative totient function](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/88777/bound-the-error-in-estimating-a-relative-totient-function) , Alan Haynes notes in an answer that Vijayraghavan in 1951 had published a result showing many $n$ for which (for certain a) the error approaches $2^{\omega(n) - 1}$.  Further, Lehmer in 1955 showed that for certain values of a (namely q/k where k divides p-1 and p divides n) that the error was 0.